# Python-Sphinx: automatically include date and time of documentation build

Tags: python-sphinx

For the Python-Sphinx documentation generator, is there a standard way to automate populating the time and date when the current rendering was built?

Looking in the `conf.py` file and at the [docs for the RTD theme](http://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html), I don't see this feature listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theme might not support it, in which case you would have to override the appropriate template.

Using [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L168-L170) as an example for what would work:

```
# If not '', a 'Last updated on:' timestamp is inserted at every page bottom,
# using the given strftime format.
html_last_updated_fmt = '%b %d, %Y'
```

In your case:

```
html_last_updated_fmt = '%b %d, %Y, %X'
```

Season your [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to taste.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to display the date/time somewhere on one page, you can use [the `|today|` substitution](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html?highlight=today#substitutions):

```
Last change: |today|
```

On my machine the result looks like this:

```
Last change: 10.07.2019
```

*(German locale, so the date is in the German format)*

To change the way the date is formatted, you can set [`today_fmt` in the configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-today_fmt), using [`time.strftime()`'s formatting directives](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

For example, if you want the date/time to look similar to the format used here on Stack Overflow, set `today_fmt` in the config file like this:

```
today_fmt = '%b %d %y at %H:%M'
```

...which will change the output of `|today|` to this:

```
Last change: Juli 10 19 at 23:34
```

*Note: according to the docs, `%b` should be the "Month as locale’s abbreviated name", so I expected the result to be `Jul` instead of `Juli`.* No idea why I get the full German month name on my machine.